# Doctrine 2 - One-To-One Automatically generate empty rows

Tags: doctrine-orm

Lets say i have 2 Entities, User and Address. Each User has to have an Address so there is an one-to-one relation between the tables.

Now i want to generate a user and it should automatically create an address row without data and just mark their relation.

Is this possible in the Entity or in the EntityRepository Class? Or is there a command that does this automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need it. Use [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) pattern.

Second, if you really need it:

```
class User { 
    public function __construct() { 
        $this->setAddress(new Address);
    }
}
```

And set [cascade persist](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations):

```
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", cascade={"persist"})
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need something like: `$address = new Address(); and $address->setUser($this);` ?

Comment: @aservedio it depends on whether the association is bidirectional or unidirectional. From the description it looks like unidirectional. Though the example of cascade persist was for bidirectional, fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Write function in Repository:

```
class User_Repository {

    public function createEmptyUserWithAddress() {
        $user = new User();
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();
        $address = new Address();
        $entityManager->persist($address);
        $entityManager->flush();
        $user->setAddress($address);
        $address->setUser($user);
        $entityManager->flush();
    } 
}
```

or extend constructor of user (or address):

```
class User { 
    public function __construct(Address $address) { 
        $this->setAddress($address);
    }
}

class User_Repository {
    public function createEmptyUserWithAddress() {
        $address = new Address();
        $entityManager->persist($address);
        $entityManager->flush();
        $user = new User($address);
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do flush more than one time. The last flush call will be enough to flush all changes.

Comment: Yeah, I know, thanks. I have written Zend plugin, which make flush in postDispatch().

Answer (score 1):

you can use the __construct() to create a relationship

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $address;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $address = new Address();
        $address->setUser($this);
        $this->address = $address;
    }
}
```